# Stopping the youtube player playback custom view

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am using a `com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView` to play my youtube videos, I extend `YouTubeBaseActivity`. I am having an issue where I call `.pause()` on the youtube player instance and and set the view `VISIBILITY` to `View.GONE` but it keeps buffering after the view has been set to `View.GONE` and throws and error because it cannot play in a hidden view. I called `YouTubePlayer.pause()` before hiding the view. Is there another way to stop playback? I want to stop the player and remove the `com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView` when a button is pressed. Thanks for taking a look.

```
if(youTubePlayer.isPlaying()){
    youTubePlayer.pause();
    youTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
```

Comment: Are you using a webview and loading the html file for that purpose? it helps if you add more detail/code to your question.

Comment: Noted, will update my question now.

Answer (score 0):

The pause function will will not stop it. You should try to release it for stopping it. Try the following code

```
youTubePlayer.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to answer - But still, someone might be benefited -

You can set player style in youtube player.

```
youtubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT) // To set player as youtube provided. 

youtubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL) // To set minimal version of the youtube player. In this style you'll not get the player control options.
```

`youtubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL)` This line will do the work of Stopping the youtube player playback custom view